# Winning Condition for Tic tac Toe Game

Tags: java, processing

I have the code of a tic tac toe game and I need some help because I dont know how to do it. ( with Processing 2.0)

1) I need to write a winning condition test. for a complete row filled by Player 1 and for player 2.

it should look like this

int rowFilledByPlayer(int row){ //code

}

2) then I need functions for testing columns and diagonals similar to the function in 1)

and then I have to combine all the functions

How can I do that ? I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my Code

```
// Global variables

int board [][] = new int [3][3]; // Game board 3x3 array
int cellWidth, cellHeight;       // Cell size computed from window size
int player = 1;
int rowFilledByPlayer;

void setup() {
  size (400, 400);
  rectMode(CORNER);
  ellipseMode(CORNER);
  // Divide window in 3 by 3 cells
  cellWidth = width / 3; 
  cellHeight = height / 3;

  clearBoard();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  drawBoard();
  if (boardFilled())
    drawGameOver();
}

void drawGameOver() {
  fill(0, 102, 153);
  textSize(width / 7);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text("Game Over!", width / 2, height / 2);
}

void mouseClicked() {
  if (boardFilled())
    clearBoard();
  else
    playerMove();
}

void clearBoard() {
  for (int row=0; row<3; row++)
    for (int col=0; col<3; col++)
      board[row][col] = 0;
}

void drawBoard() {
  for (int row=0; row<3; row++)
    for (int col=0; col<3; col++)
      drawCell(row, col);
}

void drawCell(int row, int col) {

  noFill();
  stroke(0);
  rect (col * cellWidth, row * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight);

  switch (board[row][col]) {
    case 1:
      ellipse(col * cellWidth, row * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight);
    break;
    case 2:
      line(col * cellWidth, row * cellHeight, (col+1) * cellWidth, (row+1) * cellHeight);
      line((col+1) * cellWidth, row * cellHeight, col * cellWidth, (row+1) * cellHeight);
    break;

  }
}


void playerMove() {
  int row = mouseY / cellHeight;
  int col = mouseX / cellWidth;

  if (board[row][col] == 0) {
    board[row][col] = player;
    player = oppositePlayer();
  }
}

int oppositePlayer() {
  return player = 3 - player;
}

boolean boardFilled() {
  for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
    if (!rowFilled(row))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

boolean rowFilled(int row) {
  for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
    if (board[row][col] == 0) return false;
  }
  return true;  
}

void CheckRows();
```

Comment: What was your effort so far? Did you looked at `rowFilled` method? It seems pretty good candidate to do copied to `rowFilledByPlayer` and then modified. Show us your personal effort!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to look for the three rows and the three columns if they are filled.
After that you have to check the two diagonals.
Additionally, I recommend passing the player variable throught the **boardFilled** method for a cleaner code!

This method will replace your methods **boardFilled**, **rowFilled** and **CheckRows**:

```
boolean boardFilled(int player) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (board[i][0] == player && board[i][1] == player && board[i][2] == player) {
      return true;
    }

    if (board[0][i] == player && board[1][i] == player && board[2][i] == player) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  if (board[0][0] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][2] == player) {
      return true;
  }

  if (board[0][2] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][0] == player) {
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```